# How does invalidation request works in AWS Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Let's say I create an invalidation request for the whole site, something like /* or /*/.

Does it mean that the whole content of the website will never be cached in Cloudfront again?.

I would expect the answer to be no. I guess once you create the invalidation, users will get the new version of the content and then this new content will be scheduled to be cached again in Cloudfront. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html), an invalidation request purges objects from CloudFronts cache. The next request for the object(s) is fetched from the origin and the object(s) is again stored in CloudFronts cache until either the TTL expires or until a new invalidation request is submitted.